# How do I create a bigquery pubsub direct in gcp? I get an error failed to create

Tags: google-bigquery, avro, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to publish data directly from pubsub to bigquery.
I have created a topic with a schema.
I have created a table.
But when I create the subscription, I get an error `request contains an invalid argument`

```
gcloud  pubsub subscriptions create check-me.httpobs --topic=check-me.httpobs --bigquery-table=agilicus:checkme.httpobs --write-metadata  --use-topic-schema
ERROR: Failed to create subscription [projects/agilicus/subscriptions/check-me.httpobs]: Request contains an invalid argument.
ERROR: (gcloud.pubsub.subscriptions.create) Failed to create the following: [check-me.httpobs].
```

there's not really a lot of diagnostics i can do here.

Is there any worked out example that shows? What am i doing wrong for this error?

Side note: its really a pain to have to create the BQ schema w/ its native json format, and then create the message schema in avro format. Similar, but different, and no conversion tools that I can find.

If i run with --log-http, it doesn't really enlighten:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

-- update:
switched to protobuf, same problem.
https://gist.github.com/donbowman/5ea8f8d8017493cbfa3a9e4f6e736bcc has the details.

```
gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 404.0.0
alpha 2022.09.23
beta 2022.09.23
bq 2.0.78
bundled-python3-unix 3.9.12
core 2022.09.23
gsutil 5.14
```

I have confirmed all the fields are present and correct format, as per https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto#L639

specifically:

```
{"ackDeadlineSeconds": 900, "bigqueryConfig": {"dropUnknownFields": true, "table": "agilicus:checkme.httpobs", "useTopicSchema": true, "writeMetadata": true}, "name": "projects/agilicus/subscriptions/check-me.httpobs", "topic": "projects/agilicus/topics/check-me.httpobs"}
```

I have also tried using the API Explorer to post this, same effect.

I have also tried using the python example:
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-create-bigquery-subscription#pubsub_create_bigquery_subscription-python

to create. Same error w/ a slight bit more info (ip, grpc_status 3)

debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv6:%5B2607:f8b0:400b:807::200a%5D:443 {created_time:"2022-10-04T20:54:44.600831924-04:00", grpc_status:3, grpc_message:"Request contains an invalid argument."}"

Comment: Instead of using `gcloud pubsub subscriptions create` you can try creating via REST ([subscriptions.create](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/create)). When using REST, it displays a more verbose error message on what argument is invalid.

Comment: Can you provide the topic schema and the table schema as well as the list of properties you set on the subscription?

Comment: [schema](https://gist.github.com/donbowman/87cfad5c98c4a435124b4f806aa23c93)

is the schema. As for properties, is it not all in that command line above? Or do you mean on the topic?

Comment: @RiccoD, the error i show above is from --log-http, which is the rest call.

It does a put:
```
{"bigqueryConfig": {"table": "agilicus:checkme.httpobs", "useTopicSchema": true, "writeMetadata": true}, "name": "projects/agilicus/subscriptions/check-me.httpobs", "topic": "projects/agilicus/topics/check-me.httpobs"}
```

and yields

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, I see the properties in the request. Can you also provide the BigQuery table schema?

Comment: I have alternately tried `bq mk --project_id agilicus --table agilicus:checkme.httpobs` (e.g. no schema, knowing i'd need to set it later to publish, or as shown in the gist https://gist.github.com/donbowman/87cfad5c98c4a435124b4f806aa23c93

Comment: coming back to this, i tried again w/ protobuf schema instead of avsc.
And, i generated the bigquery schema from the protobuf using https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/protoc-gen-bq-schema.

Same effect: invalid argument, no details.

Comment: I am running into the same scenario, I wish there was a utility that would generate the ZetaSQL equiv. for AVSC.